# iostream keil c++ problems

Tags: c++, iostream, keil

I am getting some errors when trying to #include iostream. I know the problem is iostream because my project compiled before, but after including iostream I have errors.

I am trying to use iostream because printf does not appear to work and I want to use cout.

I am using keil uvision 5 and yes my file is saved as main.cpp, however there are c files in my project but I would think that doesn´t matter.

Does anyone have any ideas?

oops forgot to include the errors:

```
STM324x9I-EVAL-MB1063\STM324x9I-EVAL-MB1063.axf: Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol __fread_bytes_avail (referred from ios.o).

STM324x9I-EVAL-MB1063\STM324x9I-EVAL-MB1063.axf: Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol mbsinit (referred from ios.o).

STM324x9I-EVAL-MB1063\STM324x9I-EVAL-MB1063.axf: Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol wmemmove (referred from ios.o).
```

it is also saying:

```
error in include chain (__exception.h): non-const lvalue reference to type '__builtin_va_list' cannot bind to a value of unrelated type 'va_list' (aka 'std::__va_list')

error in include chain (ostream): explicit specialization of '_C_is_cout' after instantiation
```

My main file is extremely long. I understand it is hard to say without seeing it but I am just looking for a general answer. Why would these errors ever occur in a std library file? There should be no errors in a std lib file

Comment: One idea is that you could show us your source code instead of forcing us to use our less-than-perfectly-developed psychic debugging skills :-)

Comment: You might also list your compilation line.

Comment: If `printf` "does not appear to work" it seems unlikely that iostream will do any better; it probably uses `printf` under the hood

Comment: http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: If I do understand your problem, correct me please, you are trying to use standard libraries against a specific microcontroller, presumably one from the STM32 family. Do this device embed a standard output or a console?

Answer (score 0):

Do you try to write

```
' #include "iostream"'
```

Maybe you should try to write like this:

```
'#include "iostream.h"'
```

Just my guess though

Comment: This might have been an answer, one or two decades ago.